# Getting address of Environmental Variable

Tags: c, linux, shell, gdb

I have an environment variable and I'm trying to get its memory address.  I have

```
memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);
memcpy(&buffer[517-strlen(shellcode)],shellcode,strlen(shellcode));
setenv("EGG",buffer,1);
putenv(buffer);
printf("EGG address: 0x%1x\n", getenv("EGG"));
system("bash");
```

The memory address it printed out was `0x804b00c`.  That looked incorrect.  I checked it with GDB x/x `0x804b00c`.  It said cannot access memory at `0x804b00c`. So `getenv` is basically giving me garbage memory.  I have called `env` to make sure the `EGG` variable was set, and it was.

Why cannot I get the memory address of `EGG`?

Comment: This is almost impossible for anyone to debug, besides yourself.  Too many variables.  Telling what address your environment variable lives at is moot, it could be at any address.

Comment: You do realize that environment variables are stored within your own process, right?

Comment: Why do you need the address of an environment variable? What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to invoke a root shell, and I am storing the shellcode at the environment variable so I will need to know its address.

Comment: Try printing the address with the proper format, `printf("%p\n", (void*)getenv("EGG"));`. not that it's likely to help.

Comment: This looks highly suspicious: `memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);`. Typical sploitcoders don't know C too well... Perhaps you meant `memset(buffer, 0x90, 517);` or something.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Most "sploitcoders" do know C pretty well. Jake is not a very good sploitcoder though, because he is assuming that environment variables are stored at non-randomized addresses, and is writing a nop sled on non-executable memory.

Comment: I think undefined behaviour is correct.  memset should take a pointer, not an address.

Comment: @Magn3s1um: A pointer value *is* an address. The first parameter to `memset` is of type `void*`. If `buffer` is an array object, then either `&buffer` (which is the address of the array) or `buffer` (which is the address of its first element) will be converted to the same `void*` value.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this question, another learning opportunity!

Have distilled your code to the following:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void main()
    {
      const char shellcode[] = "EGG=whatever";

      putenv(shellcode);

      printf("EGG address @%08X\n", getenv("EGG"));

      printf("EGG value is <%s>.", getenv("EGG"));

    }
```

This code works in an Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler environment.  Note, I did not have to call setenv or bash or issue a system command.  In this example, the environment variable EGG is set for the process.

Also, notice the difference between address of EGG and its actual value.  In the first case getenv returns a `char *` which is a pointer to storage as defined by the `%08X` part of the printf statement, while `%s` essentially de-references the char pointer returned by getenv.  Also, getenv() is found thru the `#include <stdlib.h>` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary answer is that you have little Endian hardware.  Thus, words (4 bytes, aligned at a word boundary) are stored with the halfwords and bytes within the halfwords, SWAPPED.  0x0804b00c is more likely really at 0x0cb04b80.

Will try writing my own c-code to do what you want and will post a second note.